# Read JSON and Iterate in Powershell

Tags: json, powershell, powershell-5.0

I have a `JSON` file where I have maintained few settings. Below is my JSON File

```
{

    "1":{
        "foundation_name":"Pre-Prod1",
        "api_url": "https://sys1.com"
    },
    "2":{
        "foundation_name":"Pre-Prod2",
        "api_url": "https://sys-2.com"
    },
    "3":{
        "foundation_name":"Prod1",
        "api_url": "https://sys5.com"
    }
}
```

And I am trying to read this `JSON` and `PRINT` it in my screen by Iterating it. Below is my `Powershell` script

```
Function FoundationSettings {
    Write-Host 'Reading from File'
    $foundations = Get-Content ".\foundations.json" -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
    Write-Host $foundations
    return $foundations
}

Function DisplayFoundations {
    $foundations = FoundationSettings
    foreach ($foundation in $foundations) {
        Write-Host 'here ..'
        Write-Host $foundation.foundation_name
    }

}
```

But it just prints this way

```
Reading from File
@{1=; 2=; 3=}
here ..
```

How to solve it ? I need to parse the JSON and at my demand i would have get the `api_url` data and `foundation_name`

Comment: Ugly. The JSON isn't using an array, but different properties with "index names" to store its objects. `$foundations | Get-Member -Type NoteProperty |% { $foundations."$($_.Name)" }` is one way to get them as a collection; I'm not sure there's not a cleaner way.

Comment: If you're still at liberty to change the format, consider something like `[{"foundation_name":"Pre-Prod1", "api_url": "https://sys1.com"}, {"foundation_name":"Pre-Prod2", "api_url": "https://sys-2.com"}]` instead. This parses much more naturally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that format is unchangeable, you can use:

```
$obj = @'
{

    "1":{
        "foundation_name":"Pre-Prod1",
        "api_url": "https://sys1.com"
    },
    "2":{
        "foundation_name":"Pre-Prod2",
        "api_url": "https://sys-2.com"
    },
    "3":{
        "foundation_name":"Prod1",
        "api_url": "https://sys5.com"
    }
}
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json

$listOfObjects = ($obj | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty).Name | % { $obj.$_ }
```

If you can change it, use JSON array where array is more appropriate:

```
$listOfObjects | ConvertTo-Json
```

Which gives:

```
[
    {
        "foundation_name":  "Pre-Prod1",
        "api_url":  "https://sys1.com"
    },
    {
        "foundation_name":  "Pre-Prod2",
        "api_url":  "https://sys-2.com"
    },
    {
        "foundation_name":  "Prod1",
        "api_url":  "https://sys5.com"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Access the value of the underlying properties:

```
Function DisplayFoundations {
    $foundations = FoundationSettings
    foreach ($foundation in $foundations.psobject.Properties.Value) {
        Write-Host 'here ..'
        Write-Host $foundation.foundation_name
    }
}
```